# How do I delete a Service?

Tags: automator, services

If I created a service using Automator, how can I delete it if I no longer want it?

Comment: (I'm not a fan of Jeopardy! style questions, but this one came up in chat, so I thought it would be good to post it)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can do this by:

1. In the **Finder**, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to Go to Folder.
2. Type "`~/Library/Services`"
3. Find the service you no longer want
4. Drag it to the Trash

Comment: This doesn't seem to remove services for selected text, e.g. right-click any selected text from Notes, you'd see a list of text-oriented services that have no .workflow under ~/Library/Services. Do you know how to cope with this?

Comment: @kakyo If you are trying to remove services that you didn’t create yourself, the program that created them may have put them in `/Library/Services/` (starting from the root of your filesystem, not your home folder) instead.